# SharePoint Online CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Testmyproject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName = "pratapbangosavi@xqsnt.onmicrosoft.com";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Password Please  ------- ");
            SecureString password = GetPasswordOfYourSite();
            // ClienContext - Get the context for the SharePoint Online Site  
            using (var clientContext = new
            ClientContext("https://xqsnt.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/"))
            {
                // SharePoint Online Credentials  
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
                // Get the SharePoint web  
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                // Load the Web properties  
                clientContext.Load(web);
                // Execute the query to the server.  
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                // Web properties - Display the Title and URL for the web  
                Console.WriteLine("Title: " + web.Title);
                Console.WriteLine("URL: " + web.Url);
                Console.WriteLine("Template: " + web.WebTemplate);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        private static SecureString GetPasswordOfYourSite()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo info;
            //Get the user's password as a SecureString  
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            do
            {
                info = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(info.KeyChar);
                }
            }
            while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
            return securePassword;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are trying to run CSOM against SharePoint Online and gets the error below.
All Contents are correct as like Site URL, Username and password.
I need to display SharePoint Site Title, URL and Template but show Error at clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH8kQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `.NET Framework` version. Please change the version to 4.6 or later to resolve this issue. If you are using `.NET Framework` under 4.6. You can add the following code to resolve this issue:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding.